# MVC5 Sequence contains no matching element

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I don't know what this error means. I'm suspecting it's this line

MVC4

`UserID = users.Single(s => s.LastName == "Wan").UserID`

to

MVC5

`UserID = users.Single(s => s.LastName == "Wan").Id`

because my application used to be MVC4 which means I needed to have a User.cs class which had UserID as the Primary key. After upgrading it to MVC5 with Identity my User.cs(ApplicationUser) needs to derive from IdentityUser. IdentityUser uses Id.

> Sequence contains no matching element

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Migrations.Configuration.Seed(ApplicationDbContext context) in C:\Users\jwan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem\RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 80
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1.OnSeed(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Sequence contains no matching element
```

Configuration.cs(Seed Method)

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models.ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        var departments = new List<Department>
        {
            new Department { DepartmentID = 1, DepartmentName = "IT"},
            new Department { DepartmentID = 2, DepartmentName = "Menzit Admin" },
            new Department { DepartmentID = 3, DepartmentName = "Human Resources"},
            new Department { DepartmentID = 4, DepartmentName = "Mechanics" },
            new Department { DepartmentID = 5, DepartmentName = "Directors" },
            new Department { DepartmentID = 6, DepartmentName = "Operations"}

        };
        departments.ForEach(s => context.Departments.AddOrUpdate(p => p.DepartmentName, s));
        context.SaveChanges();


        var depots = new List<Depot>
        {
            new Depot { DepotID = 1, DepotName = "Porana"},
            new Depot { DepotID = 2, DepotName = "Far North"},
            new Depot { DepotID = 3, DepotName = "Horowhenua"},
            new Depot { DepotID = 4, DepotName = "Manawatu"},
            new Depot { DepotID = 5, DepotName = "Silverdale"},
            new Depot { DepotID = 6, DepotName = "Christchurch"},

        };
        depots.ForEach(s => context.Depots.AddOrUpdate(p => p.DepotName, s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var users = new List<ApplicationUser>
    {
        //new ApplicationUser { FirstMidName = "Jason",   LastName = "Wan",
        //    EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1, DepotID = 1,IsAdministrator = true},
        new ApplicationUser {UserName = "adomagas@rs.kiwi.nz", FirstMidName = "Andy", LastName = "Domagas",
            EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1,DepotID = 1,IsAdministrator = true},
        new ApplicationUser {UserName = "ddjohar@rs.kiwi.nz", FirstMidName = "Denis",   LastName = "Djohar",
            EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1 ,DepotID = 1,IsAdministrator = true },
        new ApplicationUser {UserName = "cwest@rs.kiwi.nz", FirstMidName = "Christine",   LastName = "West",
            EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 2, DepotID = 3,IsAdministrator = false},

    };

        users.ForEach(s => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(p => p.FirstMidName, s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        users.ForEach(s => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(p => p.LastName, s));
        context.SaveChanges();



        var categories = new List<Category>
        {
            new Category {CategoryID = 0001, CategoryName = "Desktop"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0002, CategoryName = "Mobile"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0003, CategoryName = "Menzits"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0004, CategoryName = "XMPRO"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0005, CategoryName = "Con-X"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0006, CategoryName = "Promapp"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0007, CategoryName = "QGIS"},
        };
        categories.ForEach(s => context.Categories.AddOrUpdate(p => p.CategoryName, s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var tickets = new List<Ticket>    <-- Line 80 ERROR
        {
            new Ticket {
                UserID = users.Single(s => s.LastName == "Wan").Id, //UserID
                CategoryID = categories.Single(c => c.CategoryName == "Con-X" ).CategoryID,
                Issue = ("Con-X Login Error"),
                Priority = Priority.High
            },
            new Ticket {
                UserID = users.Single(s => s.LastName == "Wan").Id, //UserID
                CategoryID = categories.Single(c => c.CategoryName == "Desktop" ).CategoryID,
                Issue = ("Can't remote access C0123"),
                Priority = Priority.Med
            },
        };


        foreach (Ticket e in tickets)
        {
            var ticketInDataBase = context.Tickets.Where(
                s =>
                    s.User.Id == e.UserID && //UserID
                    s.Category.CategoryID == e.CategoryID).SingleOrDefault();
            if (ticketInDataBase == null)
            {
                context.Tickets.Add(e);
            }
        }
        context.SaveChanges();

    }
}
```

}

Ticket.cs

```
public enum Priority
{
    Low, Med, High
}
public class Ticket
{
    public int? TicketID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the description")]
    public string Issue { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Administrator")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select the Administrator")]
    public int IssuedTo { get; set; }
    public int Author { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No Priority")]
    public Priority Priority { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationUser : IdentityUser

```
   public class ApplicationUser
    : IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin,
        ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>, IUser<int>
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity>
            GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
        {
            var userIdentity = await manager
                .CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return userIdentity;
        }


        public bool IsAdministrator { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]

        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]

        [Column("FirstName")]
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

        public string FullName
        {
            get { return FirstMidName + " " + LastName; }
        }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
        public int DepotID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DepotID")]
        public virtual Depot Depot { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means there is no data in your users table with the last name of Wan. Single throws an error if more than 1 exists or none exist. You have commented out the line that adds "Wan" to the users table, that's why you're getting the error.

Comment: Thank you! I was being an idiot! I forgot I commented out the user.